# Fetch Request execution method returns nothing

Tags: ios, database, swift, core-data, appdelegate

In my application I use Core Data to keep some basic information about user and to easily get data I created an `Assistant` class which has a some static functions for that matter. One of them is the following:

```
static func fetchData(forEntity name: String) -> AnyObject{

        var result: AnyObject!

        let dataController = DataController().managedObjectContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: name)

        do{
            result = try dataController.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        }catch{
            print("Failed to execute fetch request for \(name) entity")
        }
        print("Returning result: \(result.description)")

        return result
    }
```

The problem is that when I use it `print("Returning result: \(result.description)")` prints "Returning result: ()" and it's not nil, it's just an empty `AnyObject` I assume. Anyway, if I then use it in this method:

```
static func getName() -> String{

        let fetched = fetchData(forEntity: "UserData") as! [UserData]

        if fetched.count > 0{
            print("Returning found value: \(fetched.first!.username!)")
            return fetched.first!.username!
        }else{
            print("Did not find any data, returning an empty string")
            return ""
        }

    }
```

It returns an empty String. However, If I use the following method inside of another class:

```
func initialize(){

        do{
            let fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UserData")
            let entities = try dataController.executeFetchRequest(fetch) as! [UserData]
            if entities.count > 0{
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.fld_name.text = entities[0].username})
            }else{
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.fld_name.text = ""})
            }
        }catch{
            print("Nope, nothing's here")
        }

    }
```

It works perfectly well and data's being read correctly.
Here's what you need to know: I use the `getName()` method in `AppDelegate`'s `application(application:, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:)` method. So it might be that the CoreData does not work correctly at that moment (which I seriously doubt)

Ok, here are my assumptions:

1. Might this problem occur because of returning `AnyObject` and therefore I lose all data?
2. Might it be because CoreData is not (somehow) yet activated at this point?
3. Is it just some other stupid mistake I make?

Please suggest your solutions. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was creating a new instance of `DataController().managedObjectContext` every time that I needed to fetch data and somehow was getting away without getting any exceptions. My solution (which worked) was to put just one instance into the delegate and use it. It worked, but, as I said, I have no idea why it works this way and doesn't in other. I'm sorry for my ignorance but I'm happy with that I just fixed it and would like to get an explanation if you can provide me with one.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues that might lead to trouble. To start, I would rewrite your fetchData function.

```
static func fetchData(forEntity name: String) -> [AnyObject] {

    let dataController = DataController().managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: name)

    do{
        let results = try dataController.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        print("Returning result: \(results.description)")
        return results
    } catch {
        print("Failed to execute fetch request for \(name) entity")
        return []
    }
}
```

The return type of `exexuteFetchRequest` is an `Array` of `AnyObject`, not just a single one.

For your `getName()` function I would do the following. It uses if let bindings to safely process your results.

```
static func getName() -> String {

    if let 
        fetched = fetchData(forEntity: "UserData") as? [UserData],
        userData = fetched.first,
        username = userData.username {
        print("Returning found value: \(username)")
        return username  
    } else {
        print("Did not find any data, returning an empty string")
        return ""
    }
}
```

Give it a whirl, and see if that helps. At a minimum, this code is far safer and far less likely to crash if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Well, first of all you'll get a warning that converting AnyObject to [AnyObject] is redundant. The problem was that I should not have made another instance of ManagedObjectContext. But thank you for your attention anyway